# Ruby convention for representing gender or sex

Tags: ruby, oop, types, conventions

What is the ruby convention is for representing a person's gender or sex when working with it as a field in an object? There is a binary gender assumption (not that I agree with this, but data is generally gathered this way).

Would you use different types for different situations? When we display this information to users, we want to display it in some meaningful way (`Male`, `male`, `M`, whatever, not `0` or `1`), and we might want to use it to sort objects by gender. My thought is to use symbols of `:Male` and `:Female` or the like, but I'd like to hear the thoughts of people with more experience in Ruby.

While I found some suggestions (writing your own substitute enum code and creating a Gender class), I didn't find anything that compared or contrasted this approach to using booleans, symbols, strings, characters, or identified it as the common convention.

Comment: I personally use either symbols `:m`/`:f` or integers `1`/`0`. With integers, by the way, you don't even have to memorize which is which. It's intuitive! :)

Comment: symbols would probably be the best choice.

Comment: While it's unlikely reasonable people will take serious offense over this point, it's useful to remember that (1) gender and sex are considered different concepts by some (basically biological properties vs. social roles and/or identity), and (2) there are people whose (gender/sex/whatever you call it) does not fit into the male/female binary, and (3) whose sex and gender (by 1) do not match.

Comment: @delnan, yes, you make important points which I agree with and are aware of. I put both sex and gender in the title for keyword purposes only, not because I believe them to be the same thing (though some searchers might!). Were I on the collecting end of data, I assure you it would be done in a much more accurate and sensitive manner, if at all, but sadly, I am merely the recipient, The data I'm currently working with assumes gender binary, that gender = biological sex, everyone has gender, and to use these assumptions to identify errors in data entry. Alas.

Comment: I would lean towards the use of a symbol, and away from classes or magic numbers. That's mostly just opinion though, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, in modern programming, especially in languages like Ruby, use of a magic number like `0`, `1` is considered a bad practice as you say. Then, the natural choice is to use a string, symbol, or specific classes for each gender/sex. For a closed class, you should avoid using a string. When using a symbol, I think it is standard to use a full word, not abbreviations, and in lower case (with underscore if it is more than a word). So I think `:male` and `:female` would be a good choice. Alternatively, you can have `Male` and `Female` classes, each with a unique object just like `FalseClass` and `TrueClass`. Or, you may simple define two `Object` instances `Male` and `Female`. Since there is no natural ordering among gender/sex, you need to define your own `<=>`.